# TideSDK add php extension

Tags: tidesdk

Is it possible to add php extensions when using TideSDK ?
I added the .dll extension in the "ext" folder in php and also added it in php.ini but I still get an error that it doesn't know the function I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is not possible as only few embedded plugins are currently supported on Tidephp. We are trying to upgrade to newer php can you provide details about which php plugin you are trying to add.

Comment: I'm actually trying to use one that's not very popular, as I noticed in the past few days googling about it :) It's php PARADOX module that I wanted to include http://php.net/manual/en/book.paradox.php

Comment: We are currently not planning to add any non default plugins.. drop by to #tidesdk on freenode if you wanna discuss this more.